# Workflow migration: retain persistent values?

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

When I migrate workflows from Development repository to Production repository, there is a chekc box "Retain persistent mapping variable values.." in migration wizard. What happens if I check this box? Does it keep e.g. values in the production environment or does it replace these values from the Development repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the option *Retain persistent values for mapping variables*, the existing values from the target folder will be kept.
Otherwise, they will be replaced with values from the source folder.

Quote from the Repository Guide:

> **Retain persistent values for mapping variables.** You can choose to retain existing values or replace them with values from the source folder.
>
> **Retain persistent values for workflow variables.** You can choose to retain existing values or replace them with values from the source folder.